# jQuery event handlers - memory usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, pointers, event-handling

I've been doing this:

```
$('#id').on('click',function(e){myFunction(var1,var2);});

function myFunction(x,y){blah blah blah}
```

I'm wanting to change to this:

```
$('#id').on('click',function(e){blah blah blah});
```

If I do this with lots of different DOM elements, am I consuming more memory space because I'm multiplying the space taken up by myFunction with each closure? Or does it just use a pointer?

Comment: darn typo, i meant "how"

Comment: @Joseph - I see! :)  It's done by AJAX when a new DOM element is created. Each element of a certain type (and class, for that matter) has the handler attached on creation. I'm now wondering whether I can just attach a handler to the class, although I think it needs the element-specific variables present at the time of creation in the function that is making the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code has the advantage of reuse, but has the disadvantage of defining an anonymous function just to call the real function. If it really matters, then the extra function is an overhead.

The second one will take much less memory since you are passing only one function. Functions are also passed by reference. Meaning this function could be stored once and called by many different callers.

---

However, the way you attach it also affects performance. If you do it like this:

```
$('#id1').on('click',function(e){myFunction(var1,var2);});
$('#id2').on('click',function(e){myFunction(var1,var2);});
```

this one calls jQuery 4 times (2 `$()` and 2 `on()`), creates 2 anonymous functions and calls an external function twice. count: 6 calls, 3 functions just to execute your operation (not including internal jQuery calls).

```
$('#id1').on('click',function(e){blah blah blah});
$('#id2').on('click',function(e){blah blah blah});
```

if you do it this way, the function isn't reusable anymore but you got 4 calls to jQuery, 2 functions but you are repeating the code. not good from a DRY perspective.

```
$('#id1, #id2').on('click',function(e){blah blah blah});
```

this one, you have 2 calls, and 1 function. this one is better.

```
$('#id1, #id2').on('click',function(e){myFunction(var1,var2);});
```

you could also do it this way, the function is reusable with a sacrifice of an additional anonymous function and call. count: 3 calls, 2 functions.

---

You could harness the power of `.on` by attaching the handler to the "nearest common parent", nearest so that the bubble won't travel up very far. in comparison, `live()` attaches events to the `document`, making handlers available even to new elements. But attaching to the `document` makes it very far for deeply nested elements.

```
$('nearest_common_parent').on('click','dynamic_element',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your second method is correct by convention. Especially, since with the first, you lose access to `$(this)`

You'd have to pass it in as a var

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {myFunction($(this), e, other_vars)});
```

VS

```
$('test').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  //yadda yadda
});
```

It really also makes your code more readable. I know I'm not answering the actual question, but I think these are some valid reasons to write your functions right in.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph's answer is an excellent explanation when primarily using ids. But if you're classes or tag names for you selectors, you would do better to leverage the `selector` parameter of the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. Example:

```
  $('#page-wrap').on('hover', 'a', function() {
    // do something
  });
```

That creates only **one** binding to `#page-wrap` element but will be fired on any `a` elements inside of it. Its better in terms of memory usage and setup speed, especially if you're binding to a lot of elements.